# How are Open Source libraries' codes structured and how can I use the library without installing it?

Tags: c++, open-source, libraries

I `git clone`d the source code for a open source library called **opencv**. Now suppose I want to modify the source code of the library (adding new functions or improving the existing ones). My question is how can see what is its effect on the library? One way could be to `make` it `make install` it again and then link the newly installed library to my project and compile it to get an executable. Is there a shorter method?

Most of the libraries in c++ seem to structured in a very similar way, which compels me to think that the answer to this is inherently related to their structure. Could please also point out some resources where I can learn about the ideology behind the structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not particular to Open Source.

Basically, you're not going to avoid `make` and link. Compiling and linking are necessary to produce an executable. (Script languages don't need this, they do the same at runtime).

`make install` might be avoided. This copies the newly created library in a standard place, so library users can easily find it. It also avoids a possible problem where a failed build breaks the installed good build. But in your case, you can link your test program against the library in its build directory.

Comment: You could either copy the header files to `./include/`, or set the include path to wherever they're currently. Don't copy the header files from openCV to your source tree, though.